# Unable to list sub direcories

Tags: vb.net, file-io

At the moment it compiles correctly but when i run open it up and click the button it adds all the files from C:\ to CheckedListBox1 but then stops...

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GetProfiles_Button.Click
        Dim rootObject As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\")
        For Each subObject As String In rootObject
            searchObject(subObject)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub searchObject(targetObject As String)
        If File.GetAttributes(targetObject) = FileAttributes.Directory Then
            Form1.CheckedListBox2.Items.Add(targetObject)
            Dim subRoot As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetObject)
            For Each subRootObject As String In subRoot
                searchObject(subRootObject)
            Next
        Else
            Form1.CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(targetObject)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the `Directory.GetFiles` function. According to the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx), this will only return files. Your check for the `FileAttributes.Directory` enumeration will always return false.

There are many examples on the net to show a recursive file and directory listing in both c# and vb.net.

**DISCLAIMER: I've copied this code from the Dot Net Perls website [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/recursive-file-directory-vbnet), rather than just linking to the code (in case the link ever dies).**

Program that recurses directories: VB.NET

```
Imports System.IO

''' <summary>
''' This class contains directory helper method(s).
''' </summary>
Public Class FileHelper

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This method starts at the specified directory, and traverses all subdirectories.
    ''' It returns a List of those directories.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Shared Function GetFilesRecursive(ByVal initial As String) As List(Of String)
    ' This list stores the results.
    Dim result As New List(Of String)

    ' This stack stores the directories to process.
    Dim stack As New Stack(Of String)

    ' Add the initial directory
    stack.Push(initial)

    ' Continue processing for each stacked directory
    Do While (stack.Count > 0)
        ' Get top directory string
        Dim dir As String = stack.Pop
        Try
        ' Add all immediate file paths
        result.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*"))

        ' Loop through all subdirectories and add them to the stack.
        Dim directoryName As String
        For Each directoryName In Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
            stack.Push(directoryName)
        Next

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Loop

    ' Return the list
    Return result
    End Function

End Class

Module Module1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Entry point that shows usage of recursive directory function.
    ''' </summary>
    Sub Main()
    ' Get recursive List of all files starting in this directory.
    Dim list As List(Of String) = FileHelper.GetFilesRecursive("C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Perls")

    ' Loop through and display each path.
    For Each path In list
        Console.WriteLine(path)
    Next

    ' Write total number of paths found.
    Console.WriteLine(list.Count)
    End Sub

End Module
```